# What models of quantum mechanics can be simulated using a quantum computer?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, quantum-information

I'm a computer scientist who's getting into quantum computing, and Im really interested in knowing what quantum simulations I can perform using a quantum computer. This might be bit broad ranged, but if I learn to use and manipulate qubits on a simulator, what all quantum experiments do you think I can achieve using it? If you could give me an idea about how many qubits would generally be required for such tasks, it will be a huge addition help :)

Comment: as asked this is too broad.  You might want to rephrase to something more specific, v.g. cracking RSA with keys of a certain length etc.

Comment: Yes you're right about being more specific, but tbh Im not so sure about all the different things I can do with quantum mechanics. Also, Im not looking for computer science stuff like RSA cracking, but something to do with quantum mechanics in general like entanglement, super position etc. Any ideas ?

Comment: a quantum computer would *use* quantum mechanics; in itself it is a processor.  It does not “entangle” particle but acts on entangled states.  Maybe a good place would be here: https://arxiv.org/abs/1804.03719 or here: https://arxiv.org/abs/1708.03684 or at least indicate how those do not answer your query.

Comment: Wow, the first link you provided is actually the paper I just started reading already! Thankyou! One more thing, will working with a quantum computer atleast allow us to test physical theories in quantum mechanics ? This is obviously far fetched and no way would be possible by myself alone, but if I tie up with a physicist, will we then be able to use such qubits to test quantum theories or no?

Comment: I think that you may get good answers on https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/ . Please see their questions and answers related to quantum chemistry on quantum computers https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/search?tab=Relevance&pagesize=50&q=chemistry

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a better fit to [https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Yes, Im sorry I didnt know about the quantum computing exchange.. Can I close this from my side ?